# Can't Understand the value of my width

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please tell me why the width of my a tag is set to auto when I explicitly set it to 60px ?

Here is my HTML (With embedded CSS) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>TestMenu </title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">

    .container{
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background-color: #eee; 
    }

    ul li a{
        width:60px;
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
    ul{
        border: red solid 1px;
        width: 492px;
    }
    ul li{
        width: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: auto;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Lundi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mardi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mercredi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jeudi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vendredi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Samedi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dimanche</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My guess is that this is due to something inherited or browser specific but I can't figure out what exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Anchor` elements are by default `inline` elements i.e. they only occupy as much space as is needed. If you want them to occupy space based on what you have specified, them you'd need to make them `inline-block`.

So, essentially you'd have to re-define your CSS class as:

```
.container ul li a {
    color:red;
    display:inline-block;       /*Add this*/
    text-align: center;
    width:60px;
}
```

You can see an example of it here->http://jsfiddle.net/jxmUY/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 5):

You have to add in this selector `display:block`:

```
ul li a{
        display:block;
        width:60px;
        text-align: center;
        color: red;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXR8S/1/)

**display: block** means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another element, for instance).

**display: inline** means that the element is displayed inline, inside the current block on the same line. Only when it's between two blocks does the element form an 'anonymous block', that however has the smallest possible width.

source: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html

Comment: `display: inline-block;` will also work if `block` impacts your layout (not back to IE6, though)

Comment: Thank you so much, it must be it.
One more question, how can I calculate the width of my ul element ?
I know it's 514px which not equal to 70*7+2

Comment: If you mean with pure css then you can use `calc`. Take a look here http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: That's not what I meant, I need to predict the width of my ul tag that contains 7 li element of 60px and 5px on left and right of each li element as my code indicates. I can't understand why ul's width is == 70*7 + 2 (border solid 1px )

Answer (score 4):

Anchors are inline elements by default, thus don't take a width. If you change them to `display: inline-block` you'll get the results you expect.

```
ul li a{
    width:60px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkrehm/W7LHw/1/